# Arrange order of evaluations (please help these unit vectors)

Tags: plotting, programming, manipulate

I need help to control order of evaluations. Here I try to use Manipulate to control n unit vectors. Their positions are initially random but head left. The 2 operations are 1) translation: moving head of each one and then the corresponding tail follows 2) rotation: moving tail of each one and then it's normalised to unit size.
(Originally I prefer the subject "helping these lovely, unit sperms".)

Although I've heard a bit about Hold/Release/Evaluation, I don't know how to control the order of evaluation to make it right.
Thanks a lot.

```
n = 5;
Do[p0[i] = {Random[], Random[]};
  q0[i] = p0[i] + {1, 0}, {i, n}];
Manipulate @@ Join[
  {Do[If[p[i] != p0[i], q[i] = p[i] + q0[i] - p0[i]; p0[i] = p[i]; 
     q0[i] = q[i]; Break[],
     If[q[i] != q0[i], q[i] = p[i] + Normalize[q[i] - p[i]]; 
      q0[i] = q[i]; Break[]]], {i, n}];
   Graphics[Table[{Line[{p[i], q[i]}], Circle[p[i], .1]}, {i, n}], 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}]},
  Table[{{p[i], p0[i]}, Locator}, {i, n}], 
  Table[{{q[i], q0[i]}, Locator}, {i, n}]]
```

Comment: This one is a bit different as I have a routine to draw each unit vector. Sorry that the code is packed.
n = 5;
Do[p0[i] = {Random[], Random[]};
  q0[i] = p0[i] + {1, 0}, {i, n}];
sperm[h_, t_] = {Line[{h, t}], Circle[h, .1]};
Manipulate @@ Join[
  {...

Graphics[Table[sperm[p[i], q[i]], {i, n}], 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}]},
  Table[{{p[i], p0[i]}, Locator}, {i, n}], 
  Table[{{q[i], q0[i]}, Locator}, {i, n}]]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Why do you think this is a problem with the order of evaluation?

Comment: As I tried, it seems the Join evaluate Do[If[...]...] and then translation and rotation fail. Sometimes Graphics fails as the parameters are not yet assigned any values. I have tried Hold/ReleaseHold/Evaluate randomly without sufficient understanding. So failed :(

Comment: A friend told me that using p[i] causes strange effect. He finally found a solution using a unified list pq and {{pq,Join[p0,q0]},Locator}. Here Locator acts like the plural "Locators" and I failed to separate p and q (to {{p,p0},Locator},{{q,q0},Locator}).